# Access to Azure Active Directory - Subscription Permission Error

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory, office365

I came across this while trying to set up [Desktop Analytics](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/mem/configmgr/desktop-analytics/overview). At "Set up your Workspace" i received the Error "You do not have permissions to register the required resource providers in this subscription".

So i started to take a look at the "Access to Azure AD" Subscription i choose for my Workspace.

Subscription Settings:

IAM: Error "The current subscription does not allow you to perform any actions on Azure resources. Use a different subscription."

My Permissions: Error "There was an error checking for access details."

Resource providers: Empty, "Register" grayed out

This appears with all "Access to AAD" Subscriptions even when logged in as GlobalAdmin with Distributor Role for the Subscriptions Management Group. Why?

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 0):

This error means that the subscription you are referencing does not host Azure AD and is a legacy subscription that can no longer be managed by a customer portal. If this subscription is causing issues, it is safe to delete it, but you can only do this by creating a [support ticket](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/support/create-ticket/).

Comment: Thank you @Marilee ! We currently have 4 subscriptions (3 x Access to AAD, 1 x disabled Pay-as-you-go). I tried to create a Supportticket yesterday, but u had to be a [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-portal/supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request#azure-role-based-access-control) 'Owner or Contributor' to do so. I can not even check who is one of that, because of the IAM Error. The next question is: If i delelete all of them, whats my default AAD Subscription (for our E3 Licence) and in which Subscription do i set up my Azure Workspace?